# Functional testing using UI Automator + Eclipse on Android devcies

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am Using Windows-10,64 bit and Eclipse. And new to UI-Automator of Google.
There is requirement for us, to automate the OS widgets and different default apps in the Mobile phone.

The below is the Project structure Image of UI-Automator Automation in eclipse.[clickHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FiwS.png)

I am using the following cmd in the prompt

```
E:\Work_Space\Appium\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools\android create uitest-project -n FirstTest -t 21 -p E:\Android_Workspace1\FirstTest
```

Please share the Appropriate videos or links to learn

Comment: Use Android Studio as shown in https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator

Comment: Thanks Diego, for your suggestion. I have setup Android studio. Its working fine now. And another question- Do we have Frame work for UI Automator. [Like in  Selenium- DDF,MDF,Hybrid F and soon]. Annotations supported [ Like in TestNG AC, BC, BT, AT and soon]. If yes, please let know. Thanks in advance.